# How to delete previously generated table in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

So this is probably pretty easy. I'm not finding anything in RubyMine documentation or Google. I previously generated a migration as:

```
Proposal name:string date:date title:string text:text user:references
```

After wanting to make a change I went through and deleted everything, or so I thought out of my rails project. This is what I get when I attempt re-generate and run db:migrate

> SQLite3::SQLException: table "proposals" already exists: CREATE TABLE
>   "proposals" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name"
>   varchar(255), "date" date, "title" varchar(255), "text" text,
>   "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at"
>   datetime NOT NULL)

So where else do I have to go to delete my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See This

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

And try in your terminal - `rake db:rollback`

Comment: Thanks after reading the migrations guide I ended up having to db:reset and choosing where to reset too.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby mine I'm not sure, but If you want to roll back the latest migration its

in your console

```
rake db:rollback
```

if you want to revert the previous generator action Ex:

```
rails g scaffold User name:string
```

and you want to revert all of the code generated

```
rails destroy scaffold User
```

HTH